# How to solve type error while using class in python?

Tags: python, oop

Today I tried the code below to add users into bank and deposit or withdraw funds:

```
class BankAccount:
    owner: str
    amount: int
    min_amount: int
    id: int

    def deposit(self, x):
        self.amount += int(self.amount) + x
test = [
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
    BankAccount(),
]
while True:
    try:
        print(
            'Press enter: \nW) to withdraw. \nD) to deposit and \nT) to do transactions and \nA) to add users \nL) to check '
            'the user information')
        response = input('>>> ')
        if response == 'A':
            test.append(BankAccount)
            user_id = int(input('Enter ID (0 to 10): '))
            test[user_id].owner = input('Enter name: ')
            test[user_id].amount = input('Enter the balance: ')
            dummy = int(input('Press enter to return.'))
        elif response == 'D':
            user_id = int(input('Enter user ID: '))
            a = int(input('Enter amount: '))
            test[user_id].deposit(a)
            dummy = int(input('Press enter to return.'))
        elif response == 'L':
            user_id = int(input('Enter user ID: '))
            print('Name: ', test[user_id].owner.capitalize())
            print('Balance: ', test[user_id].amount)
            dummy = int(input('Press enter to return.'))
        else:
            print('Invalid input!')
    except ValueError:
        print('Invalid input!')
```

Whenever I create a user and try to user the deposit option add some funds I get this type error:
self.amount += int(self.amount) + x
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: You have made your `amount` a string for some reason instead of a number.

Comment: This should be `test[user_id].amount = int(input('Enter the balance: '))` in the `response == 'A'` branch.  Otherwise the amount is initialised as a string.

Comment: You should put an `__init__` method in your class.  Also what is the purpose of the `test.append(BankAccount)` since you only work on the ten first items of your list?  (Note that by doing this you do not create a `BankAccount` object) but add the class `BankAccount` at the end of your list.

Comment: Also, in "deposit", change the += to =

Comment: Also note that `self.amount += int(self.amount) + x` will yield unexpected result after you fix the main problem you ask about. You want `self.amount += x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it's complaining that you can't perform "string + int".  This is happening because your code for making a user account takes the `amount` property as a string:

```
if response == 'A':
     test.append(BankAccount)
     user_id = int(input('Enter ID (0 to 10): '))
     test[user_id].owner = input('Enter name: ')
     test[user_id].amount = input('Enter the balance: ')  # <--- amount becomes string
     dummy = int(input('Press enter to return.'))
```

To fix this, replace this with:

```
if response == 'A':
    test.append(BankAccount)
    user_id = int(input('Enter ID (0 to 10): '))
    test[user_id].owner = input('Enter name: ')
    test[user_id].amount = int(input('Enter the balance: '))  # <--- int() makes this an integer
    dummy = int(input('Press enter to return.'))
```

Now, upon depositing, you're doing int + int, and it works! Output:

```
Press enter: 
W) to withdraw.
D) to deposit and
T) to do transactions and
A) to add users
L) to check the user information
>>> A
Enter ID (0 to 10): 1
Enter name: Yeet
Enter the balance: 10
Press enter to return.
Invalid input!

Press enter:
W) to withdraw.
D) to deposit and
T) to do transactions and
A) to add users
L) to check the user information
>>> D
Enter user ID: 1
Enter amount: 2
Press enter to return.
```

---

**One more tip**. In your class, the `deposit` function is not behaving the way you would expect. You want to add `x` (deposit amount) to the existing amount. Instead of:

```
class BankAccount:
    def deposit(self, x):
        self.amount += int(self.amount) + x   # <--- Amount = amount + amount + x, this is probably not what you want
```

You probably want:

```
    def deposit(self, x):
        self.amount += x   # <--- Amount = amount + x
```

Comment: Thanks buddy but can you explain how init() can help me with my case? because everyone is talking about it

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you chose not to include it, but be sure you have an **init**() function to create instances of your class. Here's the Python docs on classes: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: I get the point of init is to do stuff as constructor but what should I use on this init in my case?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

that's because `input` function return is a string by default, you must cast it into int for your "amount".

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you reproduce this error after adding a new user, then depositing funds?

If so, this is your issue:

```
test[user_id].amount = input('Enter the balance: ')
```

You need to convert the user input to an `int` before setting `amount`. Here is the correct code:

```py
test[user_id].amount = int(input('Enter the balance: '))
```

If you want to guard against this condition in general, I would suggest you [check out properties](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) as this will allow you to ensure you're always dealing with an `int` when you're adding to `amount`, regardless of source.

Answer (score 0):

While creating the bankaccount ( when response == 'A' ) You meant to make test[user_id] = int( input( ... ) ).
You missed the int.
Also, What is the purpose of adding the class to the list everytime an account is created?

If you meant to create an instance of the class you forgot the BankAccount *()* .